# Swift Array is Empty After Parse Queries - Completion Handler?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, block, completionhandler

I don't understand why the arrays become empty after the query with block. I did some research and it's most likely because I need a completion handler, but I can't figure out how to implement it in this case. Can I just add an activity indicator until the method is done?

```
var usernamesFollowing = [""]
var useridsFollowing = [""]

func refresh(completion: (Bool)){

    //find all users following the current user
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
    query.whereKey("following", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            //remove all from arrays
            self.usernamesFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.useridsFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            //get all userIds of following current user and add to useridsFollowing array
            if let objects = objects {

                for userId in objects {

                    var followerId = userId["follower"] as! String
                    self.useridsFollowing.append(followerId)

                    //get usernames from followerId and add to usernamesFollowing array
                    var query = PFUser.query()
                    query!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: followerId)
                    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects2, error) -> Void in

                        if let objects2 = objects2 {
                            for username in objects2 {
                                var followerUsername = username["username"] as! String
                                self.usernamesFollowing.append(followerUsername)
                            }
                        }
                        //WORKS. usernamesFollowing array is now full.
                        println(self.usernamesFollowing)
                    })
                    //BROKEN. usernamesFollowing array is now empty outside of block.
                    println(self.usernamesFollowing)

                }

            }
        }
        //WORKS. useridsFollowing is now full.
        println(self.useridsFollowing)
    })

    //BROKEN. usernamesFollowing is now empty outside of block.
    println(self.usernamesFollowing)
}
```

Comment: It's because `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is async. If you println() also a different number for each case, you'll see that they are not called in the order that you think.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Larme's point - asynchronous methods return immediately, and dispatch the work into another queue. To put this in context, consider your two `println` statements:

```
println(self.usernamesFollowing) //1. inside async fetch closure
println(self.usernamesFollowing) //2. outside async fetch closure
```

The asynchronous method will take your closure and dispatch it on to a different queue. After doing so, it returns immediately, and continues to execute your code, which goes to your **2nd** `println` statement right away. In this situation, your second `println` statement will actually print before your first.

If possible, do all your data manipulations within the block. It'll save you a lot of work. If you must offload the objects outside of the block, consider using `NSOperations`, which is perfectly equipped to deal with that type of scenario.